# How to schedule a task to run when the windows server is reboot or shutdown?

Tags: windows-server-2012, schtasks

I would like to be able to fire a task before a windows server 2012 is reboot or shutdown.

I can see task scheduler supports an 'on startup' trigger. Unfortunately there is similar event for `reboot` or `restart`. Is there anyway I can achieve the my goal?

Comment: check this link , it's simple and quick way http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-make-your-system-auto-shutdown-by-using-task-schedule/

Comment: OP is asking how to run a task AS the computer is shutting down, NOT how to run a task TO shut the computer down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the task scheduler for running scripts on shutdown, but you could instead use shutdown scripts supported by Group Policy. Shutdown scripts are run as Local System.

You can find them under **Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Before both reboot and shutdown. I have updated my question

Comment: I've been using shutdown scripts on 2008R2, but Technet says it still applies to 2012.